# TC-39 observable proposal subscriber function return value

Tags: javascript, observable

In the interface definition for the [Observable API TC-39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable) I see:

```
function SubscriberFunction(observer: SubscriptionObserver) : (void => void)|Subscription;
```

I read this as saying that the `SubscriberFunction` can return `void` or a `Subscription` type.

But in example code elsewhere I see a `SubscriberFunction` returning a method that can be used to cleanup the observable. A destructor in a sense.

Based on the above I might expect it to return a `Subscription`. What am I missing? I suspect I am parsing the IDL wrong...

**Aside**

Usage example:

```
const subscriberFunction = observer => { ... };
const observer = new Observer(subscriberFunction);

observer.subscribe({
    next(val) { ... },
    error(err) { ...},
    complete() { ... },
});
```

Comment: Can you link to the proposal? What is this `SubscriberFunction` supposed to do and how and when would it be called?

Comment: Subtle difference - it's not saying that it can return void, it's saying that it can return a function that takes zero parameters and returns void - in other words, the destructor function you mention in your question. I'm not sure if the `|` means it can *alternatively* return a `Subscription` or if it means the returned function must also implement `Subscription`, though.